# Getting Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: android-studio

I have recently moved to a Windows 10 Home 64 Bit laptop.  When I start a new project I am getting **Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream**.  This is a fresh install of Android Studio.  Has anyone else encountered this problem and if so how did you fix it?

When I look at the logs I see the following:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.RuntimeClasspathResourceHasher.hash(RuntimeClasspathResourceHasher.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.IgnoringResourceHasher.hash(IgnoringResourceHasher.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.ClasspathEntrySnapshotBuilder.visitZipFileEntry(ClasspathEntrySnapshotBuilder.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.ZipTree.visit(ZipTree.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractClasspathSnapshotBuilder$JarHasher.hashJarContents(AbstractClasspathSnapshotBuilder.java:105)
    ... 102 more
```

Comment: I have end up reloading the laptop to Windows 10 Professional and the issue seems to have gone away.  Would have like to know what the original cause of this issue was.